# Can you say "I met <an object, a thing>", eg. "I met a book"?

Tags: word-usage

Can you meet an object (not a person)? For example, is it allowed to say "I first met The Bible when I was seven years old"? In this case "to meet" would mean "to encounter" or "to get to know". Is it correct?

Comment: I don't think it's common, but it seems OK.

Comment: He never met a cake he didn’t like.

Comment: "Met", in this sense, is used but is not idiomatic except in specific contexts.  Many uses of "met" are plays on the old Will Rogers platitude "I never met a man I didn't like."

Comment: And, as for me, I never metaphor I didn't like!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. "Meet" means "encounter", and you can encounter things as well as people, although it isn't all that common to use the word except for some specific idiomatic uses. These tend to be concepts rather than objects, for example:

- He met his fate (a destiny, usually death)
- He met his end (death)
- He met his match (an equal rival)
- He met with difficulties (problems)

From other answers and comments, there are clearly examples of 'meeting' with inanimate objects in literature, but it isn't common to use it in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

[Parts of the Whole](https://books.google.com/books?id=DTFPAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA21&dq=%22met%20a%20book%22&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=%22met%20a%20book%22&f=false) a google book

> From a mother who never **met a book** she didn't read and a father who
>   never met a man he couldn't read like a book.

and

(Figurative):  "And the ground rushed up to meet me suddenly"

Your example is grammatical and correct.

Comment: A play on Will Rogers.

Comment: Yes in that jocular tone It works, but in general, “I met a book the other day at the library” just doesn’t work.